# flask-sqlalchemy stores unintended variables into database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a simple Q&A (interview and answer) with flask.
The relevant code is the following:

```
@blueprint.route("/interview/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def interview():
    rows = Question.query.count()  #counts number of rows 
    r = random.randint(1,rows)     #picks a number from 1 to 'rows'
    question=Question.query.get(r) #queries the index generated by randint

    user=User.query.get(session['user_id']) #gets session data
    created_at=''
    form = InterviewForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_answer = Answer.create(text=form.answer.data, user=user, question=question, created_at=created_at) #basically a method that combines db.session.add and db.session.commit
        flash("Your answer has been submitted")
        return redirect(url_for('interview.list', question=question.id))
    return render_template("interview/interview.html", form=form, question=question)
```

The intended result is:

1. User sees a generated random question
2. answers to the question and POSTs to server
3. insert the answer to database with
   corresponding question id (one-to-many relationship)

However, the what I get is:

- When User submits the answer, the answer is inserted to database with
  different question id

I think something is wrong with generating random number, that it generates different random integer for viewing and inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should in some way retrieve `question_id` and use it when you try save `answer`. For example, you can add hidden field to form which should store question id. In your view you should get question object using provided question_id from form(post data).

Another way, you can add question_id to your url schema, like this:

```
@blueprint.route("/interview/", methods=['GET'])
@blueprint.route("/interview/<int:question_id>", methods=['POST'])
def interview(question_id=None):
    ...
    question=Question.query.get(question_id)
    ...
```